# C++ log curve algorithm to emulate a log pot for audio

Tags: c++, math

I'm writing some firmware for a microcontroller, and I'm trying to emulate a logarithmic potentiometer with a linear digi-pot (accepts values from 0 to 255) for use in audio volume control. So far I have generated a curve from 0 to 255 by fudging an equation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
    v = pow((float)i / 64, 4);
}
```

This generates the curve named 'exp' in the chart below. By the way, log curve was generated using the `log` function, but I'm not sure that's actually the curve I need for volume control.

[image: Log and exp values]

This is similar to the curve shown in the article, [Programming Volume Controls](https://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/volumecontrols.html#ideal3), but using the equation in that article, I can't seem to generate the same curve.

[image: not-so-ideal-but-still-quite-good curve]

I would like it know what is the ideal way of generating a log curve for a linear digi-pot to emulate a log pot.

Comment: Why a log curve? The linked picture shows an approximation of the perfect volume curve as `e^6.908x / 1000` ~ `x^4` for a set range. It's the humans that perceive volume change logarithmically. If I understand correctly from a (very) quick read

Comment: @MikeNakis A bit troll like, but I'll bite. Pretty much every EE I have encountered says "pot" and not "potentiometer" (unless they're a beginner, perhaps). Its a shibboleth, and a very common one at that.

Comment: Apparently log pots are just two linear pieces that kinda sorta approximate an exponential

Comment: I think this question will find a more knowledgeable audience at either dsp.stackexchange.com or electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes, I thought about posting on EE SE instead, but maybe DSP is a better idea. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I don't know if I didn't come at the wrong party (the fact that I don't get the jokes is a strong indication), but anyway, here it goes... Is this `for` loop running on the microcontroller (in this case what functions can you use, what are the limitations), or you precompute the levels and save the resulting array to the microcontroller, in which case most of the precautions in the linked article don't apply, one  should use exp and log and solve nonlinear equations and so on.

Comment: What does "ideal" mean in this case? For instance, you could just hook the A-pot up to an oscilloscope and the plot its resistance as you sweep the pot using a linear actuator if you don't trust your hand. Now you know your specific pot's behaviour and you can approximate its LUT for applying to your B-pot's signal.

Comment: So 6.908 is just an approximation for ln(1000) to 3 decimal places. This is used because in the diagram, the range of input and output is [0,1]. To make a similar function with input and output ranges [0,255] you could just use 255*exp(6.908*x/255)/1000. For the fourth power curve, you could use 255*pow((float)i / 255, 4).

Comment: Mike: I was struggling to find the right word and “ideal” didn’t quite sit right. Perhaps I should have said “for a specific x/y value”.

Comment: Simon: Thanks, that might just be the math I’m looking for! Perhaps this is actually the answer…